# Php function to geneate multiple returns from MYSQL

Tags: php

```
function get_limit_markets(){
 $count_nodes=querydb("SELECT id,market,mkt from  markets where status= 1 
 order by market asc limit 5 ");
  $result=mysqli_fetch_array($count_nodes,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  return  array('market' => $result['market'] ,
            'mkt' => $result['mkt'],
            'id' => $result['id'] 
        );
   }


$res=get_limit_markets();
extract($res);
```

I want to create a function which will query a table markets and get the rows id, market,mkt .
I will then call the method is  seperate file and under my table

```
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Abbreviation</th>
            <th>Environments</th>
            <th>Endpoints</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php //while loop and call function to generate new row for eachc?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: What is `querydb()`? Are you getting records? what problem you are facing?

Comment: it's just a custom mysqli_query ($con,$query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return entire `$result;` rather than your created array inside function

```
function get_limit_markets(){
    $count_nodes=querydb("SELECT id,market,mkt from  markets where status= 1 
    order by market asc limit 5 ");
    $result=mysqli_fetch_all($count_nodes,MYSQLI_ASSOC); // use _all to get all records
    return  $result;
}
```

Now Apply `foreach()` to get all records and show them to table.

***So in `a.php` do like below:-***

```
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Abbreviation</th>
            <th>Environments</th>
            <th>Endpoints</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <?php 
         $res=get_limit_markets();
         foreach($res as $re){?>
             <tr>
                <td><?php echo $re['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $re['market'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $re['mkt'];?></td>
                <td>Endpoints</td>
                <td>1</td>

             </tr>


        <?php }?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Smbugua  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to fetch all of the rows from the query - `mysqli_fetch_array()` only retrieves one row.  [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) on the other hand returns all of the rows from the query...

```
function get_limit_markets(){
    $count_nodes=querydb("SELECT id,market,mkt 
                           from  markets 
                           where status= 1 
                           order by market asc 
                           limit 5 ");

    return mysqli_fetch_all($count_nodes,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$res=get_limit_markets();
print_r($res);
```

This will give you an array containing a row for each record.  You can loop over it using `foreach()` or any other method you need.

Comment: this just prints  Array()

Comment: Please read the end of the answer - you need to process the result according to your needs, I don't know what they are so how can I finish your code.